# Viewing message streams in Visual Studio for signalR chat application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, azure

I recently found a .NET tutorial that showed me how to make a simple chat application in Visual studio using the .NET library, [signalr](/questions/tagged/signalr).

I have created the application and made a few moderations including some AES encryption. I have then hosted it on Windows Azure as a website.

The chat application works and has been tested, but I don't know how to view the messages sent from one user to the other.

Can someone tell me where I can find these message streams?

Thanks

Comment: The NSA sees your messages, ask them :). Or are you working for them?

Answer (score 5):

All messages will go through the SignalR Hub, so you could either use breakpoints/debugging to see what is send (if you are running in your development environment). Otherwise you could use tracing in the Hub to see the messages.

There is a extension to glimpse that you might use (I haven't tested it though): http://www.nuget.org/packages/Glimpse.SignalR

Comment: How would you use tracing in the hub and where would this output to? @Hakan Fahlstedt

Comment: You add Trace.WriteLine-calls in your code where appropriate, and then you can set up tracing to for example write to a file at the server. A good tool to use for capturing the trace is Glimpse: http://getglimpse.com/ Just install it into your solution with Nuget and deploy the solution to the website, then you could see all the traces in the browser.

Comment: I've edited my post with a link to a Glimpse extension for SignalR.

Answer (score 1):

You can get some performance counters using the [tools provided](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/signalr-performance) by Microsoft.

For what I know there is no way to get all messages send or received from the server. When you need to analyze the communication of specific clients, try to use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or [Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865).

You could also write your own message logger that writes them to file.

You can use common methods as `Trace.WriteLine` to write info to the default listener. Then use a listener to write to file / database.

[This source](http://geekswithblogs.net/EltonStoneman/archive/2009/01/29/debugging-soap-messages-with-wireshark.aspx) may be useful when learning to analyze messages from a webserver.

Comment: Consider using Trace.WriteLine over Debug.WriteLine because the debug symbol is removed when building for release rather than debug but Trace is retained.

Comment: @JimWooley: Thanks. I have updated the answer. @sMilbz: You should use `Debug` strictly when using it for debugging purposes (sounds reasonable).

Comment: Thanks, these are great answers. How would I put a azure hosted website into wireshark? @PatrickHofman

Comment: Open your software product / browser. Start Wireshark and 'listen' to the communication to / from your webservice.

Comment: Check this: http://geekswithblogs.net/EltonStoneman/archive/2009/01/29/debugging-soap-messages-with-wireshark.aspx

Comment: @sMilbz: any luck so far? Can I help you with anything?

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) is the best tool for monitoring web traffic.  It's stupid easy to use and has a lot of extended features to help debug server/client applications.  Take a look at [this page](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Using-fiddler-with-signalr) which includes a brief description of using Fiddler with signalr.

Good luck!